# How do I calculate the noise spectral density of a RF LNA with just noise figure spec?

Tags: analog, noise, math

The LNA of of interest is PGA-105+. It says it has a noise figure of 3dB (I'm using that number my for calculations.)

That gives me a noise factor of 1.995, which is the ratio of the SNR on the input to the SNR on the output.

I tried following [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva515c/snva515c.pdf?ts=1624661082548&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) TI app note on the relationship between NF and noise voltage, but I keep getting stuck using equation 4 to convert noise figure to noise voltage. (Assuming current noise is negligible because I'm using a 50 ohm transmission line.)

The equations I am trying to use:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot calculate noise spectral density from just a single noise factor value. If you assumed the noise spectral density was constant you could, but this is a bad assumption in general. See figure 2 at your linked page for an example.

Comment: Surely if you have the NF at your frequency of interest you could.

Comment: @TimWescott I dont think I have ever seen anything called a "spectral density" given as a single value (unless its constant) so I assumed the OP was asking to calculate as a function of frequency. Im not sure what that single value would tell you anyway. I would have to think about it more, but I think that single frequency calculation would still require assuming a shape of the spectral density.

Comment: I've always worked on radios that work over voice bandwidths, so the ultimate bandwidth of the signal is too small for any frequency-dependent noise variation to change the spectral density across the IF bandwidth.

Comment: @TimWescott If that is your application then you can probably make enough assumptions to calculate noise spectral density. I'm not sure why you would want a spectral density if you already know your bandwidth, but you certainly can do it. The question doesn't include enough information to be able to make this narrow bandwidth assumption though.

Comment: @TimWescott The frequency of interest is 7MHz, I have a transmission line impedance of 50, and after the amplifier I have a LPF with a 3dB of 46 MHz. With that information would it be possible to calculate the RMS voltage noise with just the noise figure?